# Change from Sqlite in Supporting Files to Sqlite from URL

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have been dropping my sqlite DB in the supporting files of my app for testing purposes.  I'm currently trying to move this out to a URL, so I will be able to update the DB without updating the app.  I'm using the following code, which appears to be working, as it downloads the file to the Documents Directory.  Problem is I have removed the old DB from the Supporting Files and it's data is still being pulled.  I made a change in my DB so I would know the difference.

Is there some memory I need to clear out?  If not what am I missing here.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *file = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.myurl/TulsaListBars.sqlite"];
    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:file];

    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:fileURL];
    NSURLConnection *conn = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:req delegate:self];

    fileData = [NSMutableData data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [fileData setLength:0];
    totalFileSize = [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:[response expectedContentLength]];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [fileData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSArray *dirArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,    NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSLog(@"%@", [dirArray objectAtIndex:0]);

    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/TulsaListBar.sqlite", [dirArray objectAtIndex:0]];

    if ([fileData writeToFile:path options:NSAtomicWrite error:nil] == NO) {
        NSLog(@"writeToFile error");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Written!");
    }
}
```

The following code is how I read my DB.

```
-(NSMutableArray *) barList{
    thebars = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    @try {
        NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSString *dbPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath ]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"TulsaListBars.sqlite"];
        BOOL success = [fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];
        if(!success)
        {
            NSLog(@"Cannot locate database file '%@'.", dbPath);
        }else{
            NSLog(@"File Exists: %@", dbPath);
        }
        if(!(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK))
        {
            NSLog(@"An error has occured: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));

        }       

        const char *sql = "SELECT * FROM Locations WHERE bar = 'yes'";
        sqlite3_stmt *sqlStatement;
        if(sqlite3_prepare(db, sql, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement:  %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        }else{

            while (sqlite3_step(sqlStatement)==SQLITE_ROW) {
                Bar * bar = [[Bar alloc] init];
                bar.barName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement,1)];
                bar.barAddress = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement,2)];

                etc.....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The old copy of your database is still in the documents directory. If you write to file and the file already exists, `writeToFile:` should overwrite it, but of course it must have the same name / path.

Solution: Just delete the app from simulator / device and run it your app again. Also, make sure you are addressing the correct path when opening the database.

Comment: I completely reset the simulator, no change.  Deleted from actual phone as well, reset phone and still the old DB which is not included in the app.  I'm using the following when I read the file after it's downloaded.  `NSString *dbPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath ]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"TulsaListBars.sqlite"];`

Comment: It appears that the DB is loading properly in the Documents Directory, as I've checked it.  For some reason the old DB is what shows up and not the new DB.

Comment: Check the contents of the "new" database.

Comment: I did, it's correct.  It's like xcode has kept a copy of the old DB somewhere that I'm missing.

Comment: Mundi, very good, that cleaned out the old DB.  New DB is still being pulled correctly into Documents Directory, but when I go looking for that DB, I get my NSLog of 'Cannot locate database file'

Comment: Agreed, any idea why it's not finding the DB in the Documents Directory?

Comment: I left an 's' off of my file name.  Finds the file now, but says there is now no table names 'locations'.  I've checked this multiple times and there is.  The structure of the DB seems to be intact, but maybe it's not.

Comment: Best build it from scratch in code from a text file... Having come this far, you could almost accept my answer - which mentions the file name ;-)

Comment: I will accept your answer, but I was curious if you had any ideas as to how the DB in the Directory is correct, but I get a 'no such table error'

Comment: It seems to be a file name / URL name / table name / column name problem. Maybe `Locations` is spelled differently?

Comment: It's spelled correctly.  Xcode is is very inconsistant on the DB.  It sometimes appears and other times does not appear.  Very strange.  I'm sure it's me and not Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind that you cannot write to your app's bundle, and that the documents folder is separate from that. Your code example doesn't show how the database is being opened so a possibility is that it is being opened from the bundle irrespective of the downloaded file. A better approach is to put the database opening code into the didFinishLoading delegate method and to use the path of the downloaded file there.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then I still need to get the DB from the Documents Directory into the mainBundle.  Keep in mind there is no DB being included in the app bundle now, but obviously pieces of it remain somewhere.

Comment: No, because you can't put anything into the bundle at runtime, as it is readonly. You open the downloaded db file from the directory.

Comment: Also note that the simulator allows you to write to the bundle as it is running on MacOSX but iOS on the device doesn't

Comment: I've deleted the old DB, how is it still hanging around.  Is there a way to reset Xcode.